# Error in installing mysql2 ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x64-mingw32] rails 4.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

> checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
>        *** extconf.rb failed ***
>       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
>       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.
>       You may need configuration options.

```
Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib

 extconf failed, exit code 1

 Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/g   ems/mysql2-0.3.18 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-min
gw32/2.2.0/mysql2-0.3.18/gem_make.out
```

I'm stuck on this error. Don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> ```
> 1) First Install MySQL
> ```

```
  2) sudo apt-get install libmysqld-dev libmysqlclient-dev mysql-client
```

Comment: Go through this link you will get some idea how to install mysql2 in windows 7 https://medium.com/@frontlineutils/installing-the-mysql2-rubyonrails-gem-on-windows-7-8-a028f44d87f3

Answer (score 1):

If you are on OSX first you need to install mysql:

```
brew install mysql
```